# Issue with decimal placement. I have a forumla and need the average to be on the right of the decimal place

Tags: java, decimal, operation

```
  batavg = (single + Double + triple + hr) % bats;
  slug = ((single) + (Double*2) + (triple*3) + (hr*4)) % bats;
  
  System.out.println("Player name: " + player);
  System.out.printf("The currnet players batting average is: %.3f\n",  batavg);
  System.out.printf("The current players Slugging Average is : %.3f\n", slug);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are wanting to use `%` ?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "need the the average to be on the right of the decimal place"? Can you give a sample input and output?

Comment: so you want 340.000 to be 340? What about 340.5 or 340.9?

Comment: .340 is what im looking to get it to look like.

Comment: so divide your number by a thousand?

Comment: Please give us the actual output and your desired output.

Comment: Please provide more detail and the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I have basically what you are trying to get. I can't get the average to not have a zero in front, but both the Batting Average and Slugging Percentage come out to have 3 decimal places. Basically what I fixed was making the At-bats (bats) into a double value instead of an integer, and changing your modulus function into division. Here's what the code looks like.

```
//code for each int of hits are not shown

double bats = 35.0;   //this is used as a baseline
String player = "PLAYER";
double batavg;
double slug;
batavg = (single + Double + triple + hr) / bats;  //division sign used instead of % 
//(modulus will not work for this)
slug = ((single) + (Double*2) + (triple*3) + (hr*4)) / bats;

System.out.println("Player name: " + player);

System.out.printf("The current players batting average is: %.3f\n",  batavg);  
  //now there will be a decimal and 3 numbers after
System.out.printf("The current players Slugging Percentage is : %.3f\n", slug);
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck.